# Getting date string from getdate method

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, date-formatting

I need date string using sql statement like..

```
select getDate()
```

this will return `2010-06-08 16:31:47.667`

but I need in this format `201006081631` = `yyyymmddhoursmin`

How can I get this?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing formatting in SQL? DBMS were not designed to make data look pretty. For that, use a reporting tool or a middle-tier component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way

```
select left(replace(replace(replace(
   convert(varchar(30),getDate(),120),' ',''),'-',''),':',''),12)
```

or like this

```
select replace(replace(replace(
   convert(varchar(16),getDate(),120),' ',''),'-',''),':','')
```

or

```
select convert(varchar(8), getdate(),112) + 
   (replace(convert(varchar(5), getdate(),108),':',''))
```

See also: [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Another way...

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME

SELECT @d = '2010-06-09 1:37:58.030'


Select Convert(BigInt, 100000000) * Year(@d)
        + Month(@d) * 1000000
        + Day(@d) * 10000
        + DatePart(Hour, @d) * 100
        + DatePart(Minute, @d)
```

The returned data type here is a BigInt.

Answer (score 1):

Using [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx):

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, x.dt) AS VARCHAR(4)) + 
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm, x.dt) < 10 THEN '0'+ CAST(DATEPART(mm, x.dt) AS VARCHAR(1)) ELSE CAST(DATEPART(mm, x.dt) AS VARCHAR(2)) END +
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(dd, x.dt) < 10 THEN '0'+ CAST(DATEPART(dd, x.dt) AS VARCHAR(1)) ELSE CAST(DATEPART(dd, x.dt) AS VARCHAR(2)) END +
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, x.dt) < 10 THEN '0'+ CAST(DATEPART(hh, x.dt) AS VARCHAR(1)) ELSE CAST(DATEPART(hh, x.dt) AS VARCHAR(2)) END +
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(mi, x.dt) < 10 THEN '0'+ CAST(DATEPART(mi, x.dt) AS VARCHAR(1)) ELSE CAST(DATEPART(mi, x.dt) AS VARCHAR(2)) END 
  FROM (SELECT '2010-06-08 16:31:47.667' dt) x
```

For SQL Server 2005+, I'd look at creating a CLR function for format a date -- the C# [DateTime.ToString() supports providing a more normal means of formatting the date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: Why not select convert(varchar(8), getdate(),112) + 
   (replace(convert(varchar(5), getdate(),108),':',''))

Comment: @SQLMenace: I missed it when I looked at the CAST/CONVERT documentation.  Date formatting in TSQL is a PITA - the CLR option is more accommodating.

Comment: Some shops don't allow CLR, either way this should be done client side unless he needs to bcp into a file in that case there is no choice

Comment: Here is also a way that will always show 2 digits, no need for case, 

 select  RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(mm, getdate()) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)